# Loop through columns and split fields automatically to new column

Tags: r, split

I have been comparing two data frames in R using  a package called daff and this is the final table I get:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("Silva->Silva/Mark", "Brandon->Brandon/Livo", "Mango->Mango or Apple"),
               v2 = c("James->James=Jacy","NA->Na/Jane", "Egg->Egg and Orange")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

The rows fields have *->(arrow)* to mean the data was modified in that cell from previous data frame column to current dataframe value. Now from here I had to separate the columns with *->(arrow)* separator so that I can have an old column and new changed column. This means I added a suffix**_old** and **_New** to new columns. I used this code and see the output:

```
setDT(df)
df1<- lapply(names(df), function(x) {
  mDT <- df[, tstrsplit(get(x), " *-> *")]
  if (ncol(mDT) == 2L) setnames(mDT, paste0(x, c("_Old", "_New")))
}) %>% as.data.table()
```

OUTPUT

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1_Old = c("Silva", "Brandon", "Mango"),
               v1_New = c("Silva/Mark", "Brandon/Livo", "Mango or Apple"),
               v2_Old = c("James","NA", "Egg"),
               v2_New = c("James=Jacy","Na/Jane", "Egg and Orange")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Now my next step is to compare every two columns which have **_old** and **_new** suffix to identify what was modified then split and store in new column called **diff_v1**  and **diff_v2**. This I did using this code (Realise I have to do this manually by creating different spliting code lines, this is tedious with over 20 separated columns):

```
df$diff_v1<- mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), strsplit(df$v1_old, '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(df$v1_Name_new, '\\||, | | -| \\+'))
df$diff_v2<- mapply(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(y, x), collapse = '| '), strsplit(df$v2_old, '\\||, | | -| \\+'), strsplit(df$v2_new, '\\||, | | -| \\+'))
```

OUTPUT

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1_Old = c("Silva", "Brandon", "Mango"),
               v1_New = c("Silva/Mark", "Brandon/Livo", "Mango or Apple"),
               diff_v1 = c("/Mark", "/Livo", "or Apple"),
               v2_Old = c("James","NA", "Egg"),
               v2_New = c("James=Jacy","Na/Jane", "Egg and Orange"),
               diff_v2 = c("=Jacy","/Jane", "and Orange")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

My question is can I be able to loop through columns with **_old** and **_new** and create new column called **diff_v1** and **diff_v2** respectively without running code line by line since. I have multiple columns and they keep changing depending on dataframes I am comparing . Wanted to know How I can use code to automatically identify columns with **_Old** and **_New** suffix and split then create that new column after the two but should happen on each pair of columns.

Currently I have to go to the data frame, check columns with old and new then manually change in the code that is splitting and creating **diff column**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could identify `"Old"` and `"New"` columns based on their name using `grep`. We can use `str_remove` which is vectorized over `string` and `pattern` to remove part of `"Old"` col which is present in `"New"` col to create new columns.

```
old_cols <- grep("Old$", names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- grep("New$", names(df), value = TRUE)


df[sub("New$", "diff", new_cols)] <- Map(stringr::str_remove, 
                                         df[new_cols], df[old_cols])
```

To get the names in order, we can do

```
df <- df[order(sub("_.*", "", names(df)))]
df
#   v1_Old         v1_New   v1_diff v2_Old         v2_New     v2_diff
#1   Silva     Silva/Mark     /Mark  James     James=Jacy       =Jacy
#2 Brandon   Brandon/Livo     /Livo     NA        Na/Jane     Na/Jane
#3   Mango Mango or Apple  or Apple    Egg Egg and Orange  and Orange
```

---

Using `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   bind_cols(map2(df %>% select(ends_with("New")), 
                  df %>% select(ends_with("Old")), stringr::str_remove))
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I am getting this error when I run with my dataset   Error in `[.data.table`(df1, new_cols) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @LivingstoneM I think you have `data.table`. Can you change it to data.frame and then try? `df <- data.frame(df)`

Comment: sure I have done that and it works, now with the new columns I am creating, is it possible to have **diff** starting then name of column, like **diff_v1** and **diff_v2** then is it possible to have these new columns arranged just after the column pair that have been checked say example is columns be like this **v1_Old** , **v1_New**,**Diff_v1** then **v2_Old**, **V2_New**, **diff_v2**

Comment: @LivingstoneM you could do `df[order(sub("_.*", "", names(df)))]` to get them in that order.

Comment: Its just giving me the same arrangement, could you add it on your above code I try it out again